# Django database stored images showing only text descriptions

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

I am trying to store images on a database and then display them on a Django template. For some reason Django is only showing the alt (alternate - html attribute) instead of the actual image.

This is the template

```
{% extends "myapp/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}
<div class="sidenav">
    <a href="{% url 'index' %}" id="active">Gallery</a>
    <a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
    <a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <h2>Gallery</h2>
  {% for image in images %}
  <img class="gallery" src="{% static '{{image.image.url}}' %}" alt="{{image.description}}">
  {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

This is my model

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Description of image: " + self.description
```

This is what I'm seeing
[image]

Comment: Use: `src="{{ image.url }}"`

Comment: @NKSM: I think that `image` is the `Image` model object, so likely it is `{{ image.image.url }}`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, yep, you're right)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are normally media urls, so you render these with:

```
<img class="gallery" src="{{ image.image.url }}" alt="{{image.description}}">
```

You need to add the views regarding media files to the `urlpatterns`, as [described in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development).

or if these really only contain a path relative to the static folder, you work with:

```
<img class="gallery" src="{% static image.image.url %}" alt="{{image.description}}">
```

But it is *not* very likely that this is the case.

Regardless what the Note that Django only serves static/media files in debug mode (`DEBUG = True`). If you run this on production, you will need to configure apache/nginx/… to serve static/media files.

Comment: Yes, they weren't in a static file and the first solution worked. However, I don't believe the second would work, since variables need this syntax: {{ variable }}

Comment: @SajjadJessa: no, in a template tag `{% ... %}`, you do not add curly brackets, that is only to render a variable in HTML. You can pass parameters like `{% static foo %}` if `foo` is a variable.

Comment: @SajjadJessa: see for example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#firstof